# How to find component in design time easily

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I am adding some functionality to form not created by me. It has loads and loads of buttons and I would like to test if everything works by clicking on the button which executes the code I added. I know the name of this button, but I don't know it's position on the form.
 
For now I scroll through all components of the form looking for this button. If I miss it in the first lookup, I have to start over. It's tiresome and takes a lot of time.
Is there easy way? Something like "Find component" menu item, which would bring me directly to that button (or label, or anything really).

Comment: At the top of the Object Inspector, there's a combobox which lists the components of the form by name.  Have you tried using that?

Comment: I am using that to scroll through them visually. I didn't know it could be searched by typing as @Victoria suggeseted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in, comfortable way of locating components on a form (even in Delphi Tokyo). But you can search and select component in the [**Object Inspector**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Object_Inspector) Instance List combo box:

[image]

Or perform inremental search in the [**Structure View**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structure_View)'s tree:

[image]

Or install some 3rd party IDE tool. For example [**CnWizards**](http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en) toolset has the **Locate Components in Designer** tool (which is what you're looking for, I guess):

[image]

Comment: Upvoted for the CnWizards tip. I've used it for years and didn't know the locate components thing existed!

Answer (score 1):

While no help at design-time, if what you want is testing your code you likely do that at run-time:

`TComponent` has the function [`FindComponent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TComponent.FindComponent) that returns a `TComponent` owned by the calling component with matching `Name`.

As you know the name, to write test code you could use it like this:

```
var
  AButton: TButton;
begin
  AButton := Form.FindComponent(Button_Name) as TButton;
  AButton.Click;
end;
```